# Trying to call an object from a different file but the output is only displaying blanks

Tags: python

For a homework, I made an employee class file. Then I made a separate program that has a menu, from which a user can add, edit, display the content of the employee file. however, when i am trying to display, the only output coming is blank.

employee.py:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, emplpoyeeid, department, job_title):
        self.__name = ""
        self.__employeeid = ""
        self.__department = ""
        self.__job_title = ""

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_id(self, employeeid):
        self.__employeeid = employeeid

    def set_department(self, department):
        self.__department = department

    def set_job_title(self, job_title):
        self.__job_title = job_title

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_employeeid(self):
        return self.__employeeid

    def get_department(self):
        return self.__department

    def get_job_title(self):
        return self.__job_title
```

The actual program file:

```
import pickle
from Employee import Employee

try:
    filename=open('Employee.dat','rb')

    dictionary=pickle.load(filename)

except:
    dictionary={}

while True:
    print('\n1. Look up an employee in the dictionary')
    print('2. Add a new employee in the dictionary')
    print("3. Change an existing employee's name,department and job title in the dictionary")
    print('4. Delete an employee from the dicionary')
    print('5. Quit the program\n')

    choice=input('\nEnter a choice: ')

    if choice == '1':
        while True:
            employeeid=input('\nEnter the ID of the employee: ')

            if employeeid in dictionary:

                    ob=dictionary[employeeid]

                    print('Employee Name: ',ob.get_name())
                    print('Employee ID: ',ob.get_employeeid())
                    print('Employee department: ',ob.get_department())
                    print('Employee job title: ',ob.get_job_title())
                    break


            else:
                    print('\nEmployee not found \n')
                    break



    elif choice== '2':   
        while True:
            name=input('\nEnter the name of the employee: ')

            employeeid=input('\nEnter the employee id: ')

            dept=input('\nEnter the employee department: ')

            title=input('\nEnter the employee job title: ')

            ob=Employee(name,employeeid,dept,title)

            dictionary[employeeid]=ob

            print("employee has been added")
            break


    elif choice== '3':
        while True:
            employeeid=input('\nEnter the employee ID to change the details: ')

            if employeeid in dictionary:

                    ob=dictionary[employeeid]

                    while True:          

                        name=input('\nEnter the new name of the employee: ')

                        ob.set_name(name)

                        dept=input('\nEnter the new department of the employee: ')

                        ob.set_department(dept)

                        title=input('\nEnter the new job title of the employee: ')

                        ob.set_job_title(title)

                        break

            else:

                print('\nID not found \n')



    elif choice == '4':
        while True:
            employeeid=input('\nEnter the ID of the employee to delete: ')

            if employeeid in dictionary:
                    del dictionary[employeeid]
                    print('\nEmployee data removed \n ')
            else:
                    print("Employee data not found")

    elif choice == '5':

        filename=open('Employee.dat','wb')
        pickle.dump(dictionary,filename)
        filename.close()

    else:
        print('\nPlease enter a valid choice ')
```

> 1. Look up an employee in the dictionary
> 2. Add a new employee in the dictionary
> 3. Change an existing employee's name,department and job title in the dictionary
> 4. Delete an employee from the dicionary
> 5. Quit the program
>
> Enter a choice: 2
>
> Enter the name of the employee: sam
>
> Enter the employee id: 1
>
> Enter the employee department: 2
>
> Enter the employee job title: 3 employee has been added
>
> 1. Look up an employee in the dictionary
> 2. Add a new employee in the dictionary
> 3. Change an existing employee's name,department and job title in the dictionary
> 4. Delete an employee from the dicionary
> 5. Quit the program 4
>
> Enter a choice: 1
>
> Enter the ID of the employee: 1 Employee Name:   Employee ID:
>   Employee department:   Employee job title:
>
> 1. Look up an employee in the dictionary
> 2. Add a new employee in the dictionary
> 3. Change an existing employee's name,department and job title in the dictionary
> 4. Delete an employee from the dicionary
> 5. Quit the program
>
> Enter a choice:

I expected the values that i put initially to be in the second output
 but it is only displaying blanks

Comment: Please consider reducing your program to a much smaller example which just demonstrates creating an entry, writing it to the file and reading it back.

Comment: As its homework.. therefore "a hint".... look at the class and def inheritance.. `ob.get_name()` will fail eventually as you have written it right-now. Upvoted quamrana's comment ;p

Comment: This line `ob=Employee(name,employeeid,dept,title)` is not doing what you think. Add `print(ob)` beneath, to see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

First: Your `Employee` import is incorrect. If your filename is **employee.py**, you should write:

`from employee import Employee`

because your program can't find the file named Employee.py.

Second: Try not to use `while True`. It can easily throw your program in the infinite loop. For example: If you will select the fourth choice - `Delete an employee from the dicionary` - you will never return to the main menu because you can't break your infinite loop.

Third: Your `Employee.__init__` creates empty fields:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, emplpoyeeid, department, job_title):
        self.__name = ""
        self.__employeeid = ""
        self.__department = ""
        self.__job_title = ""
```

and you use no setters in the main module. Of course it will return empty strings for every field. Add setters to the main module or change `employee.py` to this:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, emplpoyeeid, department, job_title):
        self.__name = name
        self.__employeeid = emplpoyeeid
        self.__department = department
        self.__job_title = job_title
```